Angular - MSAL user missing roles
I have a backend application in entra id that has different roles - Role1 and Role2 for example. I also have a frontend app which has backend as API permission.
API:

APP:

When I use authentication on the frontend, the roles of the logged in user are not downloaded from the backend app. Which is a problem for me, because I don't want to have roles in two places and I can't because I'm working with id roles on the backend.
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
    protectedResourceMap.set(environment.graphUrl + '/me/memberOf', ['user.read']);
    protectedResourceMap.set('user.read', [environment.scope]);
    return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap,
    };
}

Is this somehow possible?
First token doesn't return any roles from the API application. (maybe is needed include scope but I don't know how)

First token:

The second token is for calling backend and there is adding scope for API application.


I created a Microsoft Entra Application (API) and exposed an API added authorized client application:

And created app roles:

In frontend application, I granted API permissions for the API application:

To get the roles in the token, make sure to assign roles to the user in the API enterprise application:

For a sample, I generated an access token via Postman:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:APPClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://APIClientID/.default 
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret


When decoded, roles and scopes are present:


But here is using client secret. I cannot use client secret in frontend application

Then refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78366047/how-to-secure-api-with-entraid/78370175#78370175

Roles in the access token depends on the configuration, you can generate the access token based on your requirement

Are you able to get the access token with the code you are using?

Maybe I spelled it wrong. I'm using MSAL library in Angular, so I can't send client secret and I send code_challenge. The frontend authenticates me against the App. Then when I call my api, it generates an access token where there is already a scope on the app api. But I would need the roles from the Api already in that first call. I have modified the question with additional information.

Did you do the configuration same as me?

Do both tokens doesn't contain roles?

You should pass the scope to get the roles in token

Yeah, I'm the same way. And I understand I need to add scope, but that's just my question I have no idea how. I couldn't do it in the msal configuration. And maybe a more general question. Shouldn't I have roles for Api and App duplicated? In the future there may be more APIs and then it makes sense to have roles for frontend and backend separately.

If you have more APIs then you have to have roles separately

What is the aud when you decode the token?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
