How to validate Entra validation token on API?
On this topic on [How to secure API with EntraID
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78366047/how-to-secure-api-with-entraid),  Rukmini helped setup the Azure app to secure an on-premise API and pass the auth token to it.
But I'm missing the part required on the API endpoint to actually validate the token and get the details of the user.
Also, the endpoint needs to be anonymous and then we do the validation by code or we can decorate it with some attributes to make it accessible only with the proper tokens?
Do you have any sample code that shows how this works?

There is this sample for ASP.NET Core: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/README.md. Check other samples from here as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype

To validate the token and get the details of the user, make use of below code:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "api://ClientID/.default" };

        var tenantId = "TenantID";
        var clientId = "ClientID";
        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            // MUST be http://localhost or http://localhost:PORT
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
        };

        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        var accessToken = await interactiveCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes));
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken.Token}");

        // Validate the token
        await ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken.Token, scopes);
    }

    static async Task ValidateTokenAsync(string token, string[] scopes)
    {
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/";

        IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager =
            new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{authority}.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

        OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        var validationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = "api://ClientID", // Actual audience in the token
            ValidIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/TenantID/", // Actual issuer in the token
            IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        try
        {
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParams, out validatedToken);
            Console.WriteLine("Token is valid.");

            // Extract user details
            var userId = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            var userName = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
            

            Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {userId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"User Name: {userName}");
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Token validation failed: {ex.Message}");
            
        }
    }
}


