Authorization issue in Azure Function (InProcess) .Net 6.0, anyone used nuget package DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.InProcess/4.1.0
I have azure function developed using .Net 6.0 InProcess mode. I have used below code for Authentication but its not working now with lastest runtime on azure portal.
Azure functions are not loading and after deployment "Sync Triggers" call is failing because of this AuthN.

here is startup file code:

I am trying to use another way to implement AuthN using nuget package found **"DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization" ** but no luck. I am getting below error while token validation.

here is code which I am trying:

As per Microsoft document with latest runtime version > 4.1 , azure functions cant use Bearer scheme and AspNetCore Authentication mechanism.
I am testing against Implicit-Flow from swagger but same has to work against Client Credential Flow as well.
**Any help/leads on this will be appreciated. **
As per Microsoft document with latest runtime version > 4.1 , azure functions cant use Bearer scheme and AspNetCore Authentication mechanism.
As per this blog , this code must have worked but its not.

Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78408841/how-to-validate-entra-validation-token-on-api

Have you tried configuring only Authority and Audience on AddJwtFunctionsBearer?
Many think audience is the same as client ID. Make sure your audience is the same as in your app registration > Expose API > API ID URI and that the token carries this value in the aud claim.
